# how to add success/error flag while returning list of object as a response

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[image][image]

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/SubmitStep1.json", method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml")
        @ResponseBody
        public List<ShopDetails> showShopList(@RequestBody ShopDetails shopDetails)throws Exception{
            List<ShopDetails> shopDetailsList=new ArrayList<ShopDetails>();
            shopDetailsList=dbq.getShopDetails(shopDetails);
            return shopDetailsList;
        }
```

Here in above code i am returning list of shops which consist details of every shop as per locality.

So, my question is , can i add a success/error message while returning if i get the list of shops.

Comment: You can wrap the `List<ShopDetails>` in a `ShopListResponse` that contains also a response status object with success/failure and the related success/failuer message.

Comment: i didn't get you. can you comment the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said @araknoid - you can create wrapper:

```
public class ShopListResponse {

private List<ShopDetails> shopList;

private String message;

public ShopListResponse (List<ShopDetails> shopList, String message){
this.shopList = shopList;
this.message = message;
}

// getters and setters
}
```

In your controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SubmitStep1.json", method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = "Accept=application/json,application/xml")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ShopListResponse> showShopList(@RequestBody ShopDetails shopDetails)throws Exception{

List<ShopDetails> shopDetailsList = dbq.getShopDetails(shopDetails);
return new ResponseEntity<>(new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, "Success or error message"), HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

If you want return an error - you can return `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND`, or just return `HttpStatus.OK` and message with error - it's depends on your approach.

Here controller result: [image]

Comment: @Optio thanks for replying but i'm getting syntax error in 

return new ResponseEntity<>(new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, "Success or error message"), HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: @RahulKumar I updated my answer, added image. All should work fine. By the way - recommend you do not throws Exception. Try to use more specific exception.

Comment: @RahulKumar if my answer helped - you can accept it.

Comment: @Optio nope, it didn't work for me. getting compile error

Comment: return new ResponseEntity<>(new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, message: "Success or error message"),HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: Do you use IDE? What does it say? What actually compile error? Please, provide more information, maybe screenshot. I believe you don't write: `new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, message: "Success or error message")`. But you should wrire: `new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, "Success or error message")`

Comment: It's not Java syntax. Please, replace with `new ShopListResponse(shopDetailsList, "Success or error message")`. Don't write word `message:`

Comment: Oh, I understand. In my screenshot you can see `message`, but it's hint from IDE (it has grey color). IDE just highlights parameter name. You don't need to write it. Here more examples of the hints: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2016/09/Screen-Shot-2016-09-27-at-10.29.15.png

Comment: You have wrong return type. You need write public ResponseEntity<ShopListResponse>. But now you have public List<ShopDetails>